# Getting Enthought Python IDLE to run code when shell is restarted

Tags: python, python-idle, enthought

I'm running EPD and using IDLE for most of my coding. What I'd like to do is get IDLE to run a script to customize my environment whenever I restart the Python shell. I've tried reading all the various posts on customizing IDLE and the Python environment, and I've yet to see anything that addresses this specific scenario. Does IDLE or EPD IDLE (if there's any difference) have a particular module it's looking for when it restarts the shell, like usercustomize.py or sitecustomize.py? Has anyone accomplished this on their own? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Upon startup with the -s option, IDLE will execute the file referenced by the environment variables IDLESTARTUP or PYTHONSTARTUP.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html#startup

Cheers,
Johannes

Comment: the python docs do say those modules are for IDLE startup, but what about when you reset the shell with ctrl+f6? Does it run those two modules? From what I read, the modules you're referring to are run once at IDLE startup, and resetting the shell will not run them a second time.

Comment: If it doesn't run these on restart, that should be considered a bug. Have you tried this and seen what happens?

Comment: See http://toolsmart.blogspot.com/2012/01/idle-restart-bug-in-python-27.html - I could not download a fix, so updated PySHell.py file manually.